# adding Matlab array's elements

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I am new to Matlab

I am trying to do something to an 2x3 array A:

1. add 10 to the highest value of A;
2. add 6 to the second highest value of A
3. add 4 to the third highest value of A
4. add 1 to the minimal value of A

for example:

A = [13 14; 19 17; 54 33];

output :[14 14; 23 17; 64 39];

is there any chance to achieve this without knowing the  elements' value inside the array?

help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the elements, we could just get indexs of them by calling `[~,I] = sort(___)` and call `A(I(k))` to find the k-th number in matrix `A`.

> [B,I] = sort(___) will return a collection of index vectors for any of
>   the previous syntaxes. I is the same size as A and describes the
>   arrangement of the elements of A into B along the sorted dimension.
>   For example, if A is a numeric vector, B = A(I).

```
%data
A = [13 14; 19 17; 54 33];

%sort
[~,index]=sort(A(:));

%add
A(index(end))=A(index(end))+10;
A(index(end-1))=A(index(end-1))+6;
A(index(end-2))=A(index(end-2))+4;
A(index(1))=A(index(1))+1;
A
```

Ref:

```
doc sort
```

Comment: @dark.o Glad that I could help. Besides, you should ask MATLAB first in the next time, since `help` and `doc` are the excellent guides for newcomers.

Comment: ok~~  I did read through the docs before posting the question though ^^

Comment: Oh, sorry. I apologize for my words.

Comment: It's ok.  Your answer helps me a lot. Thanks ~~